# Pivot a dataframe in pandas while creating additional new columns for values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | First Name | Last Name | Date of Birth | 1/1/2022 | 2/1/2022 | 3/1/2022 | 4/1/2022 | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MO12 | Wanda | Sample | 1/1/2020 | Good | Good | Good | Good | 1/1/2022 | 1/31/2022 |

I'd like to pivot the data to look like this:

| ID | Effective Date | First Name | Last Name | Date of Birth | Status | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MO12 | 1/1/2022 | Wanda | Sample | 1/1/2020 | Good | 1/1/2022 | 1/31/2022 |
| MO12 | 2/1/2022 | Wanda | Sample | 1/1/2020 | Good | 1/1/2022 | 1/31/2022 |
| MO12 | 3/1/2022 | Wanda | Sample | 1/1/2020 | Good | 1/1/2022 | 1/31/2022 |
| MO12 | 4/1/2022 | Wanda | Sample | 1/1/2020 | Good | 1/1/2022 | 1/31/2022 |

Effectively, this would turn the individually dated columns into a column called "Status" and rows with the individual dates.

I started with this basic code, but I'm getting mixed up in the syntax to create the new columns and assign the values to their respective columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\User\sample.csv')
df.pivot_table(columns=['Effective Date','First Name','Last Name','Date of Birth','Status','Start Date','End Date'],values=['1/1/2022','2/1/2022','3/1/2022','4/1/2022'], aggfunc=np.max)
df.head
```

Comment: Your sample data does not align with your expected output - i.e., last name and dob do not seem corrrect.

Answer (score 2):

Try `melt`:

```
df.melt(['ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Date of Birth', 'Start Date', 'End Date'], 
        var_name='Effective Date', value_name='Status')
```

Output:

```
     ID First Name Last Name Date of Birth Start Date   End Date Effective Date Status
0  MO12      Wanda    Sample      1/1/2020   1/1/2022  1/31/2022       1/1/2022   Good
1  MO12      Wanda    Sample      1/1/2020   1/1/2022  1/31/2022       2/1/2022   Good
2  MO12      Wanda    Sample      1/1/2020   1/1/2022  1/31/2022       3/1/2022   Good
3  MO12      Wanda    Sample      1/1/2020   1/1/2022  1/31/2022       4/1/2022   Good
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to `.set_index()` + `.stack()` + `.reset_index()`. Then just rename columns:

```py
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Date of Birth', 'Start Date', 'End Date']).stack().reset_index(name='Status').rename(columns={'level_6': 'Effective Date'})
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     ID First Name Last Name Date of Birth Start Date   End Date Effective Date Status
0  MO12      Wanda    Sample      1/1/2020   1/1/2022  1/31/2022       1/1/2022   Good
1  MO12      Wanda    Sample      1/1/2020   1/1/2022  1/31/2022       2/1/2022   Good
2  MO12      Wanda    Sample      1/1/2020   1/1/2022  1/31/2022       3/1/2022   Good
3  MO12      Wanda    Sample      1/1/2020   1/1/2022  1/31/2022       4/1/2022   Good
```